# Related to Wordnet

Tags: vocabulary

I want to find all words that occur commonly with a given word. For example the words light, sunshine, breakfast, alarm commonly occur with the word "morning".
Where can I find such information?
I hope this question is relevant on this site.

Comment: Btw, what's it about "Wordnet" here?

Comment: _Morning_ and _breakfast_ do not collocate; they just happen to be often used **near** each other. Are you looking for words that just happen to be used around each other, rather than actual collocations? For example, _baseball glove_ are collocations, while _baseball Pirates_ or _baseball Ruth_ are not; it's just that utterances that include the words _Pirates_ and _Ruth_ just happen to frequently also include the word _baseball_. There is, to my knowledge, there is no even remotely reliable way of extracting information about the latter.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "information about the latter:" This? (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/218843/14666) Araucaria's answer below.

Comment: @Kris That is still highly limited compared to what would be needed in the scenario I asked about. “Joey made me the best breakfast I’ve had in weeks this morning”, for instance, would not yield any ‘hits’ for `morning + breakfast`. Extracting statistics for this kind of ‘semantic collocation’ (for lack of a better term) would require an absolutely enormous amount of manual, multidimensional tagging.

Comment: @Janus, yes you are right, I am looking for words that just happen to be used around each other

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&#q=%22breakfast%22+NEAR+%22morning%22

Comment: @Kris, Wordnet is more general than thesaurus. But I want a sort of more generalized version of wordnet

Answer (score 6):

"all words that occur commonly with a given word" – it's called "collocation."

Look up the collocations of the word you have in mind. E.g., [morning](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=morning) in the *Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary.*

adjectives:

> this, tomorrow, yesterday | Friday, Saturday, etc. | early, late *The side of the mountain appeared pink in the early morning light.* | April, May, etc. | spring, summer, etc. | beautiful, bright, fine, sunny | cold, frosty, grey

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **concordancer**. Here's [a link to a concordancer](http://lextutor.ca/conc/eng/).

It basically searches various language corpuses, and pulls out strings of text with the given word in. You can sort by the word to the left, or to the right. You can also choose to sort be two/three/four etc words to the left or right as well. And you can set the length of the readout from 10-1000 lines.

Different concordances will be able to search in more or less detail (i.e. pull out X + adjective, or X + noun combinations). Many will also give you the frequency of the different collocations in descending numerical order. Here is a sample from a readout for  "water [word]". It's relatively short but long enough to give you an idea:

> 2571. from Frederica to painted signature The arrested WATER **shone** and danced In the
> 2572. ained but we had a problem with a little bit of a WATER **shortage** but it rained for a
> 2573. e balance Another urgent problem is the country s WATER **shortage** he added If they do
> 2574. his Its too dry really there s going to be a real WATER **shortage** still Yes a
> 2575. ivity of that task In New Zealand for example the WATER **shortages** of
> 2576. l A of Fig shows only the subjects pre exposed to WATER **showed** neophobia pre
> 2577. hovered in wavering singing clouds Sometimes the WATER **shuddered** before them as a
> 2578. speak but the effort cost her another mouthful of WATER **Shut** up and hold still a
> 2579. arina in Philadelphia it isn t as developed as uh WATER **Side** in Norfolk or the
> 2580. ements related to it i think well i m i m water a WATER **sign** and i m a fire sign
> 2581. d hold of him like this and then straight out the WATER **Silly** fool I said I don
> 2582. water Each pound of ice produces about gallons of WATER **Since** it takes calories
> 2583. been imprisoned here the last one without food or WATER **since** the guard had not
> 2584. a pan tends to rise to the top The colder heavier WATER **sinks** to the bottom and
> 2585. hat just sixty five in a bath Well not sixty five WATER **Sixty** five from the hot tap Oh
> 2586. ave a time share down there and take the boat and WATER **ski** and and go fishing
> 2587. haven t got to use it much but i love to swim and WATER **ski** and stuff like that
> 2588. s three years old How bout that That squirrel can WATER **ski** Man that s hilarious

Here we can see that the word *shortage/s* seems to have some special relationship with the word *water*. At the bottom (I've deliberately cut it off because it's too long) there are twenty-seven instances of *ski* or *skiing* and so forth. This shows a very strong relationship.

At the bottom of the readout from the concordancer that I've linked to, they also give the frequency  of each item within that selection. You need to weed out the accidental stuff, and grammatical words. Here's the reading for *water [word]*:

> and=383 in=139 the=87 to=79 gypsy=76 is=68 on=63 it=59 s=59 was=59 from=54 i=49 you=48 that=46 for=42 but=41 yeah=37 he=36 a=33 or=32 so=32 they=31 as=28 at=28 with=28 heater=27 supply=26 oh=24 she=23 then=23 of=22 out=22 when=21 which=21 if=20 all=19 pump=19 into=18 bottle=16 over=15 there=15 this=14 now=13 skiing=13 well=13 by=12 we=12 had=11 right=11 uh=11 water=11 what=11 where=11 will=11 would=11 comes=10 down=10 rafting=10 tank=10 are=9 before=9 fishing=9 like=9 no=9 off=9 only=9 up=9 aerobics=8 bill=8 colours=8 cress=8 too=8 um=8 until=8 why=8 without=8 yes=8 because=7 below=7 can=7 does=7 gets=7 line=7 look=7 sports=7 around=6 cooler=6 do=6 just=6 landing=6 mm=6 near=6 not=6 one=6 pipe=6 please=6 pollution=6 seal=6 ski=6 some=6 system=6 were=6 after=5 ah=5 between=5 coming=5 dripped=5 even=5 every=5 fish=5 has=5 here=5 his=5 leak=5 okay=5 rat=5 round=5 running=5 rushed=5 snake=5 softener=5 supplies=5 again=4 an=4 barrels=4 base=4 boils=4 bottles=4 colour=4 could=4 did=4 er=4 goes=4 heaters=4 level=4 lilies=4 looked=4 standing=4 them=4 till=4 your=4 almost=3 also=3 baby=3 bath=3 bed=3 boiled=3 came=3 chestnuts=3 color=3 come=3 contained=3 cos=3 doesn=3 dripping=3 fell=3 fountain=3 freezing=3 give=3 go=3 going=3 have=3 hot=3 ice=3 its=3 jack=3 jug=3 last=3 left=3 loss=3 mark=3 molecule=3 my=3 next=3 pipes=3 polo=3 projects=3 ran=3 rates=3 really=3 see=3 shortage=3 slowly=3 soluble=3 something=3 stops=3 systems=3 take=3 taken=3 than=3 though=3 through=3 torture=3 towards=3 two=3 under=3 while=3 within=3

You also need to be aware of which corpus you choose to select from. This one seems to have included a book about *water gypsies* so this  collocation returns a freak number of *water gypsies*. But from the above list we can pull the following collocations:

> > heater=27 supply=26 pump=19  bottle=16  skiing=13 well=13 water=11 rafting=10 tank=10 fishing=9  aerobics=8 bill=8 colours=8 cress=8 sports=7 cooler=6  landing=6  pipe=6 please=6 pollution=6 seal=6 ski=6 system=6 coming=5 dripped=5 leak=5 rat=5 round=5 running=5 rushed=5 snake=5 softener=5 supplies=5  barrels=4 base=4 boils=4 bottles=4 colour=4 heaters=4 level=4 lilies=4 looked=4 standing=4 baby=3 bath=3 bed=3 boiled=3 came=3 chestnuts=3 color=3 dripping=3 fell=3 fountain=3 freezing=3 hot=3 ice=3 jack=3 jug=3 last=3 mark=3 molecule=3 pipes=3 polo=3 projects=3 ran=3 rates=3 shortage=3 slowly=3 soluble=3 something=3 stops=3 systems=3 torture=3

If your search includes word families then the results for *colour*, *colours* and *color* would appear together, so you'd see that it would actually be fourth on that list. I find it helps to sort these kinds of results alphabetically.

The linked-to concordancer won't search by part of speech. However, many do, and the Original Poster would need to do a more specific search for *morning* using parts of speech. This is because *morning* most frequently occurs as the last word in a sentence. The words following the word *morning* are likely to have no special relationship with it whatsoever!

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The import and purpose of concordance is quite different from what the OP refers to.